# Compose NavHost composable duplicate

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```kotlin
        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = NavigationRoute.postRoute) {
            composable(NavigationRoute.postRoute) {
                Log.d(TAG, NavigationRoute.postRoute)
                PostScreen(content = this@MainActivity)
            }
            composable(NavigationRoute.settingsRoute) {
                Log.d(TAG, NavigationRoute.settingsRoute)
                SettingsScreen()
            }
            composable(NavigationRoute.imageRoute) {
                Log.d(TAG, NavigationRoute.imageRoute)
                ImageScreen()
            }
            composable(NavigationRoute.videoRoute) {
                Log.d(TAG, NavigationRoute.videoRoute)
                VideoScreen()
            }
            composable(NavigationRoute.myInfoRoute) {
                Log.d(TAG, NavigationRoute.myInfoRoute)
                MyInfoScreen()
            }
        }
```

Please tell me why the log is being duplicated.

When moving to the bottom navigation, the log is recorded multiple times.

Comment: Which log are you referring to?